# Search with subcategories with the parent category

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a tbCategories table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbCategories(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    parentId INT DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tbCategories(NAME, parentId) VALUES
('Cell Phones & Accessories', NULL),
('Computers & Accessories', NULL),
('Flip Cases', 1),
('Basic Cases', 1),
('Cell Phones', 1),
('Tablets', 2),
('Laptops', 2),
('Desktops', 2);
```

and a tbProducts table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbProducts(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    category INT,
    price FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO tbProducts(NAME, category, price) VALUES
('Apple iPhone 8 64GB Space Gray', 5, 449.00),
('Samsung Galaxy S10', 5, 464.99),
('Huawei P30 Pro', 5, 719.99),
('Samsung Note 10+', 5, 902.49),
('Samsung A10', 5, 149.90),
('Lenovo Chromebook', 7, 219.55),
('ASUS ROG', 7, 930.00);
```

I want to access products in the sub-category through the parent category in the search query.
I tried this, but I noticed this was wrong query.

```
SELECT id, name, price FROM tbProducts WHERE (category=? OR category = (SELECT id FROM tbCategories WHERE tbCategories.parentId=?)) AND name LIKE ? OR productCode LIKE ? OR productionCode LIKE ?
```

Because more than one data comes from the subquery. I think I need to use **JOIN**, but I can't. Can you help please?
The result I expected: I will search in the parent category, for example, when I search for "Samsung" in the "Cell Phones & Accessories" category, it will search for "Flip Cases, Basic Cases, Cell Phones" in all subcategories of the "Cell Phones & Accessories" category and give me results.
I explained it in writing. I don't know how else I can tell you.

Comment: Can you add what results you are expecting?

Comment: @CarlBinalla I added

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `JOIN`

```
SELECT PRO.id 
     , PRO.name
     , PRO.price 
  FROM tbProducts PRO 
  JOIN tbCategories CAT 
    ON PRO.category = CAT.id 
  JOIN tbCategories CAT2 
    ON CAT2.id = CAT.parentId 
 where PRO.name = 'Samsung Galaxy S10'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It only searches in subcategories, but there are also categories that are the parent category by itself, with no subcategories.